# Apache2 directories sites avaliable and sites enabled Difference

Tags: apache

I am creating a VirtualHost on my apache whilst going through configurations i noticed two Directories:

sites-avalible & sites-enabled

both directories have vhost.config files and their content looks the same.

What is the difference between these two and in which directory should i configure my vhost.config....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files look the same because they're basically the same: They're [symlinked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link). Every 'file' in sites-enabled links to a file in sites-available. Because of this, it doesn't matter if you edit the links in sites-enabled or the actual files in sites-available. Here's an output of a sample sites-enabled dir - see the arrows pointing to files in sites-available?

```
root@somehost:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled# ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct  1 12:07 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Oct  9 12:04 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   46 Aug 18 10:59 firstsite.com -> /etc/apache2/sites-available/firstsite.com
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   53 Aug 14 16:53 secondsite.com -> /etc/apache2/sites-available/secondsite.com
```

The reason for this is that it enables us to configure VirtualHosts and activate/deactivate them whenever we want.

You can, for example, create a new config file in sites-available and include it in the config any time by either directly symlinking it `ln -s /dir/dir/sites-available/newconfig.conf /dir/dir/sites-enabled/` or using the builtin apache tools, e.g. [a2ensite](http://man.he.net/man8/a2ensite) and a2dissite

Note that you have to reload the apache config afterwards to include the new/edited config

Comment: ok thats sounds interesting, lets say I have a vhost.config in sites-enable directory this would mean I can access site, but if I move this vhost.config file to sites-avalible I can no longer access this site...what about if I have the same file in both directories...?

Comment: only the files in sites-enabled are used when apache loads its config so if you move one out of sites-enabled or delete a symlink sitting there, it won't be included in the running config once you reload apache. The folder names are self-explanatory ;)

Comment: OK thank you very much for you information, I agree the directories are self-explanatory as long as you know whats going on xD if you not sure then its not so 'self-explanatory' xD

Comment: Answer accepted ;) would also upvote it but apparently I dont have enough reputation points hehe